# Disable power management on network cards

Tags: powershell

The below code worked perfectly, though I did observe a very brief disconnect in the RDP session. is it normal ?

```
    $Adapters = Get-NetAdapter -Physical |Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -like "*vmxnet3*" } | Get-NetAdapterPowerManagement
ForEach ($A in $Adapters) {
    $A.AllowComputerToTurnOffDevice = 'Disabled'
    $A | Set-NetAdapterPowerManagement
}
```

Comment: What RDP session? We don't know the context or local environment you're working in, how and from where you're invoking the script, and none of us can see your screen :)

Answer (score 0):

`Set-NetAdapterPowerManagement` will probably [restart the network adapater per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/set-netadapterpowermanagement?view=windowsserver2022-ps) unless you explictly ask it not to restart the adapter with `-NoRestart`. But... if you use `-NoRestart` you may find the setting doesnt take effect until next time the NIC or the entire computer/server is restarted.